# Can I enter Romania with a single entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, passports, germany, romania

I'm currently a holder of a single entry Schengen visa and I'm planning to visit Germany next month. Is it possible that after my stay in Germany to visit Romania using the same single entry visa I used to enter the German territory ?

Thank you in advance for your kind reply.

Answer (score 10):

No, this is not allowed. [According to the Romanian Ministry of Foreign Affairs](http://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040):

> Starting July 11, 2014, in keeping with the provisions of Decision No 565/2014/EU, Romania acknowledges as being equivalent to its own national visas, for transit and for stays up to 90 days per period of 180 days the following:
>
> - The two or multiple entry short-stay visa issued by a Schengen member state;
> - ...
>
> Attention! The number of entries as well as the right of stay established as per the Schengen visas must not have been exhausted.

As your visa is a single-entry visa, it is not usable for entry to Romania. You will have to apply for a separate Romanian visa.